# Javascript Objects (dynamic attribute names)

Tags: javascript, object

if I have an object, something like this

```
var o = {
  test : 1
}
```

and I would like to have a second object, one of it's keys should be the value of o.test.
Something like this:

```
var o2 = {
   o.test : "bla"
}
```

I know this is not possible, but is there a better (cleaner) way to do it as I do this now?

Currently what I dow is this:

```
var o2 = {};
o2[o.test] = "bla"
```

I guess there is a better way for this?

Comment: `o2[o.test] == o2[1]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I guess there is a better way for this?

Assuming I've understood your question correctly then no, not really. The way you've shown is the way to do it. There is no way to use a dynamic key inside the literal itself, so you have to declare it first and then assign the property separately:

```
var o2 = {};
o2[o.test] = "bla";

o2; // { 1: "bla" }
```

---

**Update**

The full details are given [in the spec](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.5). Here's the grammar for object literal property identifiers:

> *PropertyName* :
>     *IdentifierName*
>     *StringLiteral*
>     *NumericLiteral*

The *StringLiteral* production is self-explanatory. Here's what the *IdentifierName* production does:

> The production *PropertyName* : *IdentifierName* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Return the **String value** containing the same sequence of characters as the *IdentifierName*.

And for the *NumericLiteral* production:

> The production *PropertyName* : *NumericLiteral* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *nbr* be the result of forming the value of the *NumericLiteral*.
> 2. Return **ToString**(*nbr*).

You can see from this that it is not possible to use anything other than a string inside an object initialiser.

Comment: mhm, I hoped there was a better way for this, I could have saved a few lines of code then. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your Object properties can be any string

```
var o = {
  "whatever you want":1,
  "1":"numbers too"
}
o[2]="no numbers, convert to string"

console.log(o["whatever you want"]);//=1
console.log(o["1"]);//=numbers too
console.log(o[new String(2)]);//=no numbers, convert to string
// as James commented, you don't have to convert to string
// I usually do that as to not confuse the object with an array
console.log(o[2]);//=no numbers, convert to string
```

If all your "property names" are positive integers or 0 you could use an array:

```
var arr=new Array();//or var arr=[];
var b=22;
arr[10000]="hi";
arr[b]="value";
// normally you would do for(var i=0;len=arr.length;i<len;i++){...arr[i]
// but because there may be many empty spots it's quicker to do:
for(thing in arr){
  if(arr.hasOwnProperty(thing)){
    console.log(thing  + " is " + arr[thing]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say *any string*, as the declaration can only use constants. As demonstrated, once initialised the object can use any string for a property.

Comment: @RGraham correct, you can't declare number values as object names in the "body" of the object literal so I guess the answer to the OP's question is no.

Comment: @HMR - You don't have to convert the number to a string. That's done automatically. See the *PropertyName* : *NumericLiteral* production from the grammar in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This being javascript, there is almost always a workaround for doing what you want.

There is no **syntax** for doing what you want but you can certainly write a function to do it:

```
function make () {
    // Optional sanity check:
    if (arguments.length % 2) throw "Number of arguments should be even!";

    var obj = {};
    for (var name=0,val=1; name < arguments.length; name+=2,val+=2) {
        obj[arguments[name]] = arguments[val];
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Now you can write this:

```
var o2 = make(
    o.test,        'bla',
    'another_key', 'another_val'
);
```